Hot water heater hose leaking that transfers water from the tank to the house
My gas, hot water heater is leaking from the hose that puts the hot water into the house I was wondering if I could leave the pilot on and just drain the tank low enough to replace the hose??

Pilot lights are usually not that hard to relight.  With the pilot left on, the burner will come on when the temperature drops enough.  For a couple minutes saved, turning it completely off sounds good.

Thank you for your comment. I was just wondering if I can leave the pilot light on because I was nervous to mess with the gas because I have never done it before

I am nervous around gas also, but there should be instructions on the heater/nearby showing how to turn off/turn on.  If no instructions, they should be online for your heater.

You should turn off the pilot - it's easy to relight it!  As suggested, this will also give you an opportunity to flush out your hot water heater.
However, you can do what you're suggesting if you have an isolation valve on the hot water outlet side of the tank after the hose or if the house plumbing is all at or below the level of the HW heater.  Otherwise there is a risk of hot water backflowing from the house pipes.
If you have an isolation valve that will block backflow from the house, close the valve, then shut off the cold water flowing into the tank, then drain several gallons (maybe 1/4 of the tank) from the bottom drain of the heater.
At that point you should be able to safely remove the hot water hose and repair it, but be careful. If the shutoff valve is leaking water into the HW heater it could raise the level of the hot water in the tank back out through the hot water outlet.

That is not a quick fix, but it is a easy fix.
First you have to empty the tank completely and reduce the pressure to zero in order to be able to fix the leak.
You would stat with closing the cold water inlet then emptying the tank.
For that you will need to shut off the gas valve and the pilot light.

Most hot water tanks have their outlets at the top.  Draining the pipe and a bit of the tank should be enough.  Tank pressure is mainly from cold water going in plus a bit of heating.  It would be a good time to flush the tank by draining completely, but not required.

@crip659 - As mentioned in my answer, it would depend on the level of the house plumbing, whether it is above or below the HW heater. The water in the house lines may backflow.

I finally got it replaced, but now the other hose that brings the cold water into the tank the faucet that shut off and on is leaking

Reverse the process. Turn off the isolation valve on the hot water side. Partially drain the tank and  then replace/repair the cold water line. Again, it's best to shut down the pilot during this process but not required.
